# Get Contact(s) in Acumatica via RESTful API

Tags: acumatica, filemaker

@HB_ACUMATICA, et al,

I've been working on integrating a client's FileMaker database with Acumatica for the past few months. I'm able to access (get/put) various tables (entities), such as PROJECT and CUSTOMER, but the CONTACT entity always produces an error. For example,

`https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer` [works fine]

`https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact` [always an error 500]

**[EDIT: The above examples are, of course, incomplete, unless trying to find 'all' Contact records. In testing, I was specifying actual Contact IDs, as in,

```
https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer/Nobody
```

where 'Nobody' is a real Contact ID... or so I was led to believe... see my answer below]**

Everywhere I have looked in the documentation, it indicates "Contact" is the proper name for the Entity. What am I doing wrong?

Much thanks.
-- Erik

Comment: Are you passing the ContactID as parameter ?

Comment: The 500 response usually contains a body with error description. What error are you getting?

Comment: It seems to be because of delegate on AddressValidated, I'll try to craft an answer that exclude that field that make the request fail.

Comment: Have you tried to extend service endpoint, create a custom endpoint for Contact and add only the fields you need except `Default Address->Validated`? After doing it I can get all the records from Contact endpoint.

Comment: @Rick, Yes, I have tried "https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact/Nobody," for example (when there is a Contact with ID "Nobody").

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, The error (header) is: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @IntelligentDB, what is the error response _body_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue that hasn't been fixed yet. The error message returned by the web service call is:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:\r\nAddressValidated: View AddressCurrent has BQL delegate\r\n",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.CannotOptimizeException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.NotWorkingOptimizedExportProvider.get_CanOptimize() in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R21-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\OptimizedExport\\NotWorkingOptimizedExportProvider.cs:line 84\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R21-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 116\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetListImpl(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R21-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\SoapFacadeBase.cs:line 83\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.GetList(String objectName, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2017R21-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\SystemContracts\\V2\\RestController.cs:line 247\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

The error occurs when fetching field `AddressValidated`. However that field isn't even returned by the request. **EDIT it is returned only when the Address Validation feature is activated**

As a workaround what I did is fetch a single contact by ContactID and then copy all the field name returned. I then put those fields in the `select` clause of the request which specifies which field should be returned. This appears to have the side effect of not involving `AddressValidated` and the call succeeded:

```
https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/?$select=Active,AddressIsSameAsInAccount,BusinessAccount,CompanyName,ContactClass,ContactID,ContactMethod,ConvertedBy,DateOfBirth,DisplayName,DoNotCall,DoNotEmail,DoNotFax,DoNotMail,Duplicate,DuplicateFound,Email,Fax,FaxType,FirstName,Gender,Image,JobTitle,LanguageOrLocale,LastIncomingActivity,LastName,LastOutgoingActivity,MaritalStatus,MiddleName,NoMarketing,NoMassMail,Owner,OwnerEmployeeName,ParentAccount,Phone1,Phone1Type,Phone2,Phone2Type,Phone3,Phone3Type,QualificationDate,Reason,Source,SourceCampaign,SpouseOrPartnerName,Status,Synchronize,Title,Type,WebSite,Workgroup,WorkgroupDescription
```

---

As Samvel Petrosov mentioned you can also extend the endpoint and remove the `AddressValidated` field from there (this doesn't seem to apply for fields coming from default endpoint, only use for customized fields):
[image]

With that approach you would have to change the endpoint in the URL to the extended endpoint name ('DefaultPlus' in this example):

```
https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/DefaultPlus/18.200.001/Contact
```

Comment: This error disappears after removing the `Validated` field from the endpoint.

Comment: Yes makes sense, I wonder why AddressValidated is not returned for single entity though.

Comment: Found out why, when address validation feature is not activated the field is not returned. It doesn't affect the failure with delegate though, I'll update my answer to add endpoint extension option.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, I tried to remove that field from my extended Endpoint, but when I click the [X] a red X appears next to the field. The row doesn't disappear. The X disappears if I do anything else (there is no option to 'save' yet).

Comment: mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/DefaultPlus/18.200.001/Contact/Nobody?$select=ContactID

yields the same error 500

Comment: In your original question you are fetching all contacts, here you are fetching contact 'Nobody'. If there is indeed a 'Nobody' contact I wouldn't expect a 500 error, regardless of the presence of a select clause. Can you inspect the response body which contains the error message?

Comment: Apparently you can't delete fields which are coming from Default Endpoint so I'm not sure that solution is valid.

Answer (score 0):

[WRONG: Data Field is 'Display Name' — 'ContactID' is 102155, not 'Wegweiser, Erik'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8w9Z.png)

Aha! Thank you, all for the potentially useful information that may come in handy down the line. However, these issues and my concern about not doing something correctly turned out to be 'red herrings.' Once again, Acumatica's strange inconsistency in following its own conventions had befuddled me.

I was attempting to execute a request in the same format as elsewhwere, e.g.
`https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer/ACME001` (where 'ACME001' is a real Customer ID), works fine and all is good. Whereas,
`https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact/Nobody` (where 'Nobody' is a real Contact ID) does not work.

Why? Despite my skepticism and the better judgment that 30 years of database programming experience tells me that Acumatica's 'ContactID' is not a wise implementation for a unique record identifier... I believed what I was told. Right there in the Element Properties inspector, it says that the real name of the field, labeled "Contact ID" is indeed, 'ContactID.'

When I eventually tried another form of query,

```
https://mydomain.acumatica.com/entity/Default/18.200.001/Contact?$filter=LastName eq 'Wegweiser'&$select=FirstName,ContactID
```

I finally received the payload that showed me the truth:
Unfortunately, what was elsewhere identified as 'ContactID' and, according to convention, reasonably taken as the unique identifier, is actually the sensibly-named 'DisplayName.'
The real 'ContactID,' as one would expect, is the true unique ID.

Acumatica is a wondrous tool. It's just a real different animal with many heads (or some might be tails), iMHO.

---

**EDIT by HB_ACUMATICA**

Looking at `Contact.ContactID` field definition in `Contact` DAC it is indeed declared as an `Integer` field and doesn't have a custom attribute that would return a `String` display value on screen:

```
#region ContactID
public abstract class contactID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible)]
[PXPersonalDataWarning]
public virtual Int32? ContactID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

With this DAC definition alone it is indeed incoherent that the field shown on screen is of `String` type instead of `Integer`. The explanation to this behavior is that the `Contact Screen` uses the `ContactMaint` graph which redefines the `Contact.ContactID` DAC field using the `CacheAttached` mechanism:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact ID")]
[ContactSelector(true, typeof(ContactTypesAttribute.person), typeof(ContactTypesAttribute.employee))]
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
public virtual void Contact_ContactID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```

Notice that the `Contact.ContactID` field redefinition adds a `ContactSelector` attribute that wasn't present in `Contact` DAC. A quick look at that attribute reveals it is using the `Description` field of `PXSelector` to show `DisplayName` string on screen instead of the `Integer` value. This substitution is only for display purpose in screens bounded to `ContactMaint` graph, all database operation remains `Integer` based. ContactSelector excerpt:

```
public ContactSelectorAttribute(bool showContactsWithNullEmail, params Type[] contactTypes)
    : base(GetQuery(typeof(Contact.contactID), showContactsWithNullEmail, contactTypes))
{
    if (contactTypes == null || contactTypes.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contactTypes));

    DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName);         
}
```

The REST web service call isn't using the `Contact` DAC instead of `ContactMaint` graph, that's why it requires an `Integer` instead of a `String` value.

Comment: I edited your answer to add an explanation to the Integer/String mismatch behavior in Contact screen vs REST Web Service.